# Setting the width of columns with an array as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
function LoadColWidth(thewidtharray) {

    for (i = 0; i < thewidtharray.length; i++) 
    {
        $('#MyGrid .tr:first').eq(i).width(thewidtharray[i]);
    }
};

var NarrowWidth = new Array(70, 72, 97, 72, 97, 72, 96, 76, 76, 76, 76, 75);
```

I'm calling LoadColWidth with different arrays as the parameter and the goal is to resize the width of columns. I'm struggling with the jquery call: it's supposed to loop through each columns by index but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `<td>` elements in the first row, and iterate over them using the [`each()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

Inside the `.each()`, use the index parameter it provides to select from your Array of widths.

```
 // Use the "index" parameter--------------v
$('#MyGrid tr:first > td').each(function( i ) {
    $(this).width( thewidtharray[i] );
});
```

Or here's an alternative if you're using `jQuery 1.4.1` or later:

```
 // Use the "index" parameter---------------v
$('#MyGrid tr:first > td').width(function( i ) {
    return thewidtharray[i];
});
```

Comment: This works. However, I'm actually looking to loop only through the columns of a certain class and I haven't been able to make the code look to see if the column is of the class .MyClass. Working on it but kinda stuck...

Comment: @frenchie: I just noticed that your code has a misplaced `.` before `tr:first`, which I ended up copying. Fixed. If you're only targeting `td` elements with a certain class, you'd do `$('#MyGrid .tr:first > td.myClass')`. I may be able to give a better answer if you provide a sample of your `table` in your question.

Comment: So, should I remove the dot or keep it? The table is a gridview; some columns are of class MyClass and some are not.

Comment: @frenchie: I made the same copy/paste error in my comment, but fixed it in my answer. You're selecting a `<tr>` element, so you do *not* want the `.` before `tr`. `$('#MyGrid tr:first > td.myClass')`

Comment: ...or use `th` if that's what you have in the first row `$('#MyGrid tr:first > th.myClass')`

Comment: I got it: $('#MyTable th.MyClass').each(function(i) {
    $(this).width( arr[i] );
});